# Chrome's "Default" user directory locked

Tags: google-chrome, locked-files

Chrome would not start.
I spotted the problem down to the following situation:

The following folder
`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`
is locked - always. Also when chrome is not running. Also immediately after a reboot.

Furthermore, I tried to unlock it with both the "***unlocker***" and "***lockhunter***" applications. 
Both applications claim that the folder is not locked, however, when asking them to rename it they fail.

Comment: Found the asnwer: the "default" folder was locked by an application called "easy file locker" which I installed once for some purpose.

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)